# Не получается собрать проект в jar файл

Tags: spring, gradle, jar, сборка

Не понимаю как собрать готовый jar файл c помощью Gradle'a. Сам файл появляется в папке libs, но не запускается по причине отсутствия зависимостей

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
> > at com.example.dogovorimsyaaskbot.DogovorimsyaAskBotApplication.main(DogovorimsyaAskBotApplication.java:10)
> > Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
> > at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> > at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> > at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> > ... 1 more

Файл Build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
```

}

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'



java {
sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'}

repositories {
mavenCentral()}

    dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation group: 'org.telegram', name: 'telegrambots', version: '6.4.0'

implementation 'org.telegram:telegrambots-spring-boot-starter:6.8.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j
implementation group: 'com.mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-j', version: '8.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '3.1.3'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api
implementation group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.2.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.2.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api
compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.10.0'
}


jar{
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 
`'com.example.dogovorimsyaaskbot.DogovorimsyaAskBotApplication'
}`

}
/*
jar {
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 
'com.example.dogovorimsyaaskbot.DogovorimsyaAskBotApplication'
}
}*/



tasks.named('test') {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Файл settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = 'DogovorimsyaAskBot'
```

Comment: Не ваш случай? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61198694/5479247